# Select last distinct records in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I have a table in mysql have a lot of data.i want to display only distinct and last saved data...here is what i have

```
CREATE TABLE amounts(
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    bank_id INT,
    amount INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT INTO `amounts` (`id`, `bank_id`, `amount`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '100'),
(NULL, '2', '200'),(NULL, '3', '300'),(NULL, '1', '500'),(NULL, '2', '600'),
(NULL, '1',   '800'),(NULL, '2', '50');
```

I want result like this

```
  bank_id    amount
  1           800
  2            50
  3            300
```

how will be select query for this?

Comment: There's no guarantee that AUTO_INCREMENT values will in fact be sequential, so there is no way telling which record was inserted last. Use timestamps to have unambiguous information about insertion time.

Comment: @mchl they might not be sequential, but they surely will be always increasing

Comment: Not surely. See multimaster replication setup and auto_increment_increment and auto_increment_offset settings here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-master.html
Your SQL code should never assume anything about how your server is configured.

Comment: @Mchl thanks for the link... I'm having a look at it!

Comment: Sure. This will be a rare occurrence, but like I said, never assume anything about server.

Comment: @Mchl This is not a big deal,Ok i agree with you, i have timestamp also...you please give me solution....

Comment: You can use the answer you accepted below, just use timestamp column for comparison:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT a.bank_id, 
       b.amount 
FROM   (SELECT bank_id, 
               Max(id) AS id 
        FROM   amounts 
        GROUP  BY bank_id) a 
       INNER JOIN amounts b 
               ON b.id = a.id
```

**Result**

```
| BANK_ID | AMOUNT |
--------------------
|       1 |    800 |
|       2 |     50 |
|       3 |    300 |
```

### [See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17a64/1)

Answer (score 2):

Use a self join. This is almost always faster than a subquery.

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM amounts a LEFT JOIN amounts b ON a.bank_id = b.bank_id AND a.id < b.id
  WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

### [See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eebf0/17)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery where you select max IDs for every bank_id, then you select all rows whose IDs are returned by this subquery:

```
SELECT amounts.*
FROM   amounts
WHERE  id IN (select max(id)
              from amounts
              group by bank_id)
ORDER BY bank_id
```

Please see [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eebf0/14).

Comment: don't know why my answer and njk answer got a downvote... they are both correct, and there's nothing wrong with using a subquery

Comment: A knee-jerk reaction of people who have read once that 'subqueries are evil' without delving into what kinds of subqueries are slow and how this has been addressed in newer versions of MySQL